# In AWS, how to create elastic ip with boto3 ? or more generaly with python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'd like to create an elastic ip with a python script. It didn't find a way in the doc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Allocate Address](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.allocate_address)

> Acquires an Elastic IP address.
>
> An Elastic IP address is for use either in the EC2-Classic platform or
>   in a VPC. For more information, see Elastic IP Addresses in the Amazon
>   Elastic Compute Cloud User Guide

```
    import boto3

    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    addr = client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')
    print addr['PublicIp']
```